# Blender addon generating basemesh from floor plan

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am developing an addon that generates walls from a .dxf floor plan. It can read the dxf file, but it only generates a bunch of layers in the viewport and shows the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\ziggurat\Desktop\python addon\my_script.py", line 90, in execute
    wall_objs = create_walls(self.filepath)
  File "C:\Users\ziggurat\Desktop\python addon\my_script.py", line 71, in create_walls
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
RuntimeError: Error: Object 'Wall.007' already in collection 'Scene Collection'
```

Here is my code that creates the layers in diagonal order, and I don't know why, I just know that I should snap them and stick them in the correct order to each other:

```
import bpy
import ezdxf
import os

def create_wall(start, end, thickness, height, name):
    # Calculate the length and direction of the wall
    x1, y1, z1 = start
    x2, y2, z2 = end
    dx, dy, dz = x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1
    length = ((dx ** 2) + (dy ** 2) + (dz ** 2)) ** 0.5
    
    # Check for zero length to avoid division by zero error
    if length == 0:
        print("Error: zero length wall")
        return None
    
    direction = (dx / length, dy / length, dz / length)

    # Create a new mesh for the wall
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)

    # Create vertices for the wall
    verts = [
        (0, 0, 0),
        (0, height, 0),
        (thickness, height, 0),
        (thickness, 0, 0)
    ]
    # Scale and translate the vertices to form the wall
    transformed_verts = []
    for vert in verts:
        transformed_vert = [
            (vert[0] * direction[0]) + start[0] + (vert[1] * direction[1]) + start[1] + (vert[2] * direction[2]) + start[2]
            for vert in verts
        ]
        transformed_verts.append(transformed_vert)

    # Create faces for the wall
    faces = [(0, 1, 2, 3)]

    # Create a new object for the wall
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)

    # Link the object to the scene collection
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
        # Assign the vertices and faces to the mesh
    mesh.from_pydata(transformed_verts, [], faces)

    # Calculate normals and update mesh
    mesh.update()

    return obj
def create_walls(dxf_path):
    doc = ezdxf.readfile(dxf_path)
    msp = doc.modelspace()
    wall_objs = []
    for obj in msp:
        if obj.dxftype() == "LINE":
            start = obj.dxf.start
            end = obj.dxf.end
            thickness = 0.2
            height = 2.5
            name = "Wall"
            wall = create_wall(start, end, thickness,height, name)
            wall_objs.append(wall)
    # Add the wall objects to the scene
    for obj in wall_objs:
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
    return wall_objs
class ImportFloorPlanOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "import.floor_plan"
    bl_label = "Import Floor Plan"
    bl_description = "Import a floor plan from a DXF file"
    
    filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="File Path",
        description="Path to the DXF file",
        subtype="FILE_PATH"
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        # Check if the filepath is empty
        if not self.filepath:
            self.report({"ERROR"}, "No file selected")
            return {"CANCELLED"}
        # Call the create_walls function to create the wall objects
        wall_objs = create_walls(self.filepath)
        # Add the wall objects to the scene
        for obj in wall_objs:
            context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
        return {"FINISHED"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        # Open a file browser to select the DXF file
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

class ImportFloorPlanPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "IMPORT_FLOOR_PLAN_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Import Floor Plan"
    bl_category = "Floor Plan"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        props = layout.operator("import.floor_plan", text="Import Floor Plan")
        props.filepath = ""

classes = [
    ImportFloorPlanOperator,
    ImportFloorPlanPanel,
]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image: the planes in viewport]

Comment: Hello. Adding an object to the same collection twice throws an error. You can either add a try/except to silently pass, test `if obj in collection.objects` or fix this in the code : You want to remove either instances of `bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)`

Comment: BTW the mesh creation process is a bit weird. In Blender Z is up, not Y. Your faces container only support a single face, so your walls will be rectangles ? I don't really understand the `transformed_verts` purpose ?